# how to give full width to table cell in react + material?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, material-design, material-ui

I am using material UI with react .I am showing my data in table.Actually in table I have some `titles` example `"
GENERAL_INFORMATION"` and `INFORMATION` are the titles .I want to show this in middle .But my `table cell` is not taking width 100% why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/qlj0l8yrx9

```
 <Fragment>
                    <TableRow key={row.id}>
                      <TableCell> {title}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    {row.map(({ displaytext, value }) => (
                      <TableRow key={row.id}>
                        <TableCell>{displaytext}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </Fragment>
```

I am taking help from this url
https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

Answer (score 9):

how about: https://codesandbox.io/s/wo9n5vvjvk

i just modify line:84

```html
<TableCell colspan="2" style={{ "text-align": "center" }}>
```

Comment: what is use of `colspan ..please help me understant`

Comment: This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many columns the cell extends. [click me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)